# Função sem retorno

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou seguindo um Livro de estudos OO e me deparei com um problema relacionado a uma chamada de método.Vou contextualizar com as Classes.

```
<?php

    class Orcamento{

        private $itens;

        public function adicionar(Produto $produto, $qtde){
            $this->itens[] = array($qtde, $produto);
        }

        public function calculaTotal(){
            $total = 0;

            foreach ($this->itens as $item) {
                // echo "<pre>";print_r($item[0]);die();
                echo "<pre>";print_r($item[1]);die();
                // echo "<pre>";var_dump($item[1]->getPreco());die();
                $total +=($item[0] * $item[1]->getPreco());
            }
                // die($total);
            return $total;
        }

    }

?>
```

---

```
<?php

    class Produto{
        private $descricao;
        private $estoque;
        private $preco;

        public function __construct($descricao, $estoque, $preco){
            $this->$descricao = $descricao;
            $this->$estoque = $estoque;
            $this->$preco = $preco;
        }

        public function getPreco(){
            return $this->preco;
        }

    }


?>
```

---

Cria Orçamento

```
    $orcamento = new Orcamento();

    $orcamento->adicionar( new Produto('Maquina de café', 10, 299), 1);

    $orcamento->adicionar( new Produto('Mesa de vido', 10, 170), 1);

    $orcamento->adicionar( new Produto('Barra de chocolate', 10, 7), 3);

    // echo "<pre>";print_r($orcamento);die();

    print $orcamento->calculaTotal();

?>
```

É um exemplo usando agregação o problema é que sempre que o método getPreco é chamado o mesmo não retorna nada.O mais estranho que executando os die o Objeto possui todos os Atributos corretos(quantidade e preço).Tanto que ao executar o die na linha 16 do arquivo Orcamento.php o retorno é esse :

```
Produto Object
(
    [descricao:Produto:private] => 
    [estoque:Produto:private] => 
    [preco:Produto:private] => 
    [Maquina de café] => Maquina de café
    [10] => 10
    [299] => 299
)
```

Agora eu não sei se é um erro de sintaxe ou um erro de estrutura.

Comment: `$this->$preco = $preco`, não existe este $ antes de preço, deveria ser `$this->preco = $preco`

Comment: assim como o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou, vc tem o mesmo erro reptindo aqui `$this->$descricao = $descricao; $this->$estoque = $estoque; $this->$preco = $preco;`, depois das `->` não tem o `$`, isso explica o porque de estar vazio esses valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja:

```
    public function __construct($descricao, $estoque, $preco){
        $this->$descricao = $descricao;// aqui 
        $this->$estoque = $estoque;//     aqui
        $this->$preco = $preco;//         e aqui
    }
```

Pois você está colocando o `$` para definir um elemento do objeto, depois de `$this->` nas três linhas, deveria ser assim:

```
    public function __construct($descricao, $estoque, $preco){
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        $this->estoque = $estoque;
        $this->preco = $preco;
    }
```

Pode verificar que os valores que não aparecem são:

```
[descricao:Produto:private] => 
[estoque:Produto:private] => 
[preco:Produto:private] =>
```

Que correspondem à esses três erros respectivamente.

Comment: Foi exatamente esse o problema ,inclusive o calculo deu certo .Obrigado pelo toque em relação aos erros eu achei que era a forma do PHP apresentar atributos privates.

Answer (score 1):

Você criou um array de array.

Então quando for percorrer o vetor itens[] fique atento na seguinte informação

```
Array[0] =>
     [ '0' => quantidade, '1' => Produt1],
Array[1] =>
     ['1' => quantidade, '1' => Produt2],
Array[2] =>
     ['0' => quantidade, '1' => Produt3],
Array[3] =>
     ['1' => quantidade, '1' => Produt4],
Array[4] =>
     ['1' => quantidade, '1' => Produt5],
Array[5] =>
     ['0' => quantidade, '1' => Produt3],
Array[6] =>
     ['0' => quantidade, '1' => Produt4],
Array[7] =>
     ['0' => quantidade, '1' => Produt5],
```

Perceba que tem que percorrer dois vetores
O primeiro é posicionar o item e o segundo extrair quantidade e o produto instanciado.

Use var_dump($vetor ou object);
Com var_dump você visualiza como está saindo os dados com mais detalhes.
Mas erro é pq não implementou usando essa lógica de percorrer vetor.